# Make Literal Object have Parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, object, parameters

Currently I'm using Javascript to display animals and their info on a HMTL Page.

Currently its showing the Image of a bunny and info like this:

> *BUNNY IMAGE*
>   **Age Range:** 3 months - 2 Years
>   **Max adopt:** 1-2
>   **Bonded Pairs:** Yes
>   **Needing homes:** 5

I need to make the Age range, max adopt  etc a parameter instead of just manually making the text bold and writing it. here's my JS:

```
var bunny = {
  animalName: 'Bunny',
  bondedPairs: '<b>Bonded Pairs: </b> Yes',
  maxAdopt: "<b>Max adopt: </b> 1-2",
  ageRange: "<b>Age Range: </b> 3 months - 2 Years",
  needingHomes: '<b>Needing homes: </b> 5',
  avatarSrc: '../images/bunny.jpg',
  note: 'note: We have lots of adorable fluffy loafs looking for their forever homes.',

  createProfile: function() {
    //creates a div to store their staff info
    var profile = document.createElement("div");
    //sets the class
    profile.className = "animalProfile";
    //creates a new image for the profile pic
    var avatar = document.createElement("img");
    //sets the source and name based on our object info
    avatar.src = this.avatarSrc;
    avatar.alt = this.animalName;
    //appends the image to the profile div
    profile.appendChild(avatar);
    //sets up the text
    var profileTxt = document.createElement("p");
    profileTxt.innerHTML = "<b>" + this.animalName + "</b><br />" +
      "</b><br />" + this.ageRange + "</b><br />" + this.maxAdopt +
      "  </b><br / > " + this.bondedPairs +
      "</b><br />" + this.needingHomes;

    //adds the text to the profile div
    profile.appendChild(profileTxt);
    //returns the completed profile
    return profile;
  }
}

document.getElementById("animal_list").appendChild(bunny.createProfile());
```

```js
var bunny = {
  animalName: 'Bunny',
  bondedPairs: '<b>Bonded Pairs: </b> Yes',
  maxAdopt: "<b>Max adopt: </b> 1-2",
  ageRange: "<b>Age Range: </b> 3 months - 2 Years",
  needingHomes: '<b>Needing homes: </b> 5',
  avatarSrc: '../images/bunny.jpg',
  note: 'note: We have lots of adorable fluffy loafs looking for their forever homes.',

  createProfile: function() {
    //creates a div to store their staff info
    var profile = document.createElement("div");
    //sets the class
    profile.className = "animalProfile";
    //creates a new image for the profile pic
    var avatar = document.createElement("img");
    //sets the source and name based on our object info
    avatar.src = this.avatarSrc;
    avatar.alt = this.animalName;
    //appends the image to the profile div
    profile.appendChild(avatar);
    //sets up the text
    var profileTxt = document.createElement("p");
    profileTxt.innerHTML = "<b>" + this.animalName + "</b><br />" +
      "</b><br />" + this.ageRange + "</b><br />" + this.maxAdopt +
      "  </b><br / > " + this.bondedPairs +
      "</b><br />" + this.needingHomes;

    //adds the text to the profile div
    profile.appendChild(profileTxt);
    //returns the completed profile
    return profile;
  }
}

document.getElementById("animal_list").appendChild(bunny.createProfile());
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: navy;
  font-family: 'Sofia', cursive;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16pt;
  text-align: center;
}

.animalProfile {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  width: 320px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.animalProfile img {
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #4d4d4d;
}

.animalProfile p {
  font-size: 12pt;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Animal Adoption</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sofia" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/adopt_styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <h1 id="heading" class="blueTxt">Our Animals to Adopt</h1>
    </header>
    <p>All our animals are available to adopt to proven loving and caring homes with responsible owners.</p>
    <section>
      <div id="animal_list">

      </div>

    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="../js/animal_script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It looks like the bold part is always the same. It would be more logical that such text is static in your HTML and not part of the object values. Any reason why "note" is *not* in bold?

Comment: How would i go about doing this?

Comment: Did any of the answers suit your needs? Could you give some feed back?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to be able to show a *list* of one *or more* bunnies. So you I would suggest creating an array of objects, and create those objects with a constructor (one can use the ES6 `class` syntax for that).

Also, it is preferable to separate code that accesses the HTML document from any other code.

And why not use the template literal syntax (using backticks) to produce the HTML for representing one bunny. That could be a method of the Bunny class.

Here is how that would look:

```js
class Bunny {
    constructor(animalName) {
        this.animalName = animalName;
    }
    asHtml() {
        return `
        <div class="animalProfile">
            <img src="${this.avatarSrc}" alt="${this.animalName}">
            <p>
                <b>${this.animalName}</b><br><br>
                <b>Age Range: </b>${this.ageRange}<br>
                <b>Bonded Pairs: </b>${this.bondedPairs}<br>
                <b>Needing homes: </b>${this.needingHomes}<br>
                <b>Max adopt: </b>${this.maxAdopt}<br>
            </p>
        </div>`;
    }
}

// Create all the bunnies
const bunnies = [];
let bunny;

bunny = new Bunny("Rabbit");
bunny.bondedPairs = "Yes";
bunny.maxAdopt = "1-2";
bunny.ageRange = "3 months - 2 Years";
bunny.needingHomes = "5";
bunny.avatarSrc = "../images/rabbit.jpg",
bunnies.push(bunny);

bunny = new Bunny("Squirrel");
bunny.bondedPairs = "No";
bunny.maxAdopt = "1-3";
bunny.ageRange = "3 months - 3 Years";
bunny.needingHomes = "4";
bunny.avatarSrc = "../images/squirrel.jpg",
bunnies.push(bunny);

// Show them on the page
const list = document.getElementById("animal_list");
for (let bunny of bunnies) list.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", bunny.asHtml());
```

```css
body { background-color:lightblue; }   
#container { margin: 0 auto; width:80%; }
header { width:100%; text-align:center; }
section { width:100%; text-align:center; }
h1 { color:navy; font-family:'Sofia', cursive; font-size:2.5em; padding-top:20px; }
p { font-family:'Quicksand', sans-serif; font-size: 16pt; text-align: center; }
.animalProfile { display: inline-block; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5); }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <h1 id="heading" class="blueTxt">Our Animals to Adopt</h1>
    </header>
    <p>All our animals are available to adopt to proven loving and caring 
  homes with responsible owners.</p>
    <section>
        <div id="animal_list">

        </div>
    </section>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Not so much a parameter that is used, but the object keys instead. As I am not sure where you would otherwise want to get your parameters from. Now just looping all object keys except for avatarSrc and createProfile. This does have the advantage that you can add more properties to other animals that will automatically be displayed.

If you have more animals with an identical createProfile function then it would also make sense to get that function out of your objects and only have it once on itself.

```js
var bunny = {
  "Animal Name": 'Bunny',
  "Bonded Pairs": 'Yes',
  "Max Adopt": "1-2",
  "Age Range": "3 months - 2 Years",
  "Needing Homes": '5',
  avatarSrc: '../images/bunny.jpg',
  Note: 'We have lots of adorable fluffy loafs looking for their forever homes.',

  createProfile: function() {
    //creates a div to store their staff info
    var profile = document.createElement("div");
    //sets the class
    profile.className = "animalProfile";
    //creates a new image for the profile pic
    var avatar = document.createElement("img");
    //sets the source and name based on our object info
    avatar.src = this.avatarSrc;
    avatar.alt = this['Animal Name'];
    //appends the image to the profile div
    profile.appendChild(avatar);
    //sets up the text
    var profileTxt = document.createElement("p");

    const keys = Object.keys(this);

    keys.forEach((key) => {
      if(this.hasOwnProperty(key) && key !== 'avatarSrc' && key !== 'createProfile') {
      profileTxt.innerHTML += '<b>'+ key + ':</b> ' + this[key] + '<br/>';   
      }
    });
    
    //adds the text to the profile div
    profile.appendChild(profileTxt);
    //returns the completed profile
    return profile;
  }
}

document.getElementById("animal_list").appendChild(bunny.createProfile());
```

```html
<div id="animal_list"/>
```